# Cassandra migrate int to bigint

Tags: cassandra, cql

What would be the easiest way to migrate an int to a bigint in Cassandra? I thought of creating a new column of type bigint and then running a script to basically set the value of that column = the value of the int column for all rows, and then dropping the original column and renaming the new column. However, I'd like to know if someone has a better alternative, because this approach just doesn't sit quite right with me.

Answer (score 1):

You could `ALTER` your table and change your `int` column to a `varint` type. Check [the documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/cql_data_types_c.html#concept_ds_wbk_zdt_xj__cql_data_type_compatibility) about `ALTER TABLE`, and the [data types compatibility](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/cql_data_types_c.html#concept_ds_wbk_zdt_xj__cql_data_type_compatibility) matrix.

The only other alternative is what you said: add a new column and populate it row by row. Dropping the first column can be entirely optional: if you don't assign values when performing insert everything will stay as it is, and new records won't consume space.

Comment: I was looking at the varint type, but I couldn't figure out exactly what the difference is between that and a bigint. I suppose since the varint maps to a java BigInteger, that should be sufficient, because all I really care about is that it is big enough, and I think BigInteger technically has no upper bounds. Are there any other differences as far as Cassandra is concerned in terms of space, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

You can `ALTER` your table to store bigint in cassandra with `varint`. See the example-

```
cassandra@cqlsh:demo> CREATE TABLE int_test (id int, name text, primary key(id));
cassandra@cqlsh:demo> SELECT * FROM int_test;

 id | name
----+------

(0 rows)
cassandra@cqlsh:demo> INSERT INTO int_test (id, name) VALUES ( 215478936541111, 'abc');
cassandra@cqlsh:demo> SELECT * FROM int_test ;

 id                  | name
---------------------+--------- 
     215478936541111 |  abc

(1 rows)
cassandra@cqlsh:demo> ALTER TABLE demo.int_test ALTER id TYPE varint;
cassandra@cqlsh:demo> INSERT INTO int_test (id, name) VALUES ( 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999, 'abcd');
cassandra@cqlsh:demo> SELECT * FROM int_test ;

 id                                                                                                                           | name
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------
                                                                                                              215478936541111 |  abc                                                                                                     
 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999 | abcd

(2 rows)
cassandra@cqlsh:demo>
```